# Проблема получения ответа от Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia

Формирую такой запрос к API для получения информации с статьи которую нашёл:

```
https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&namespace=0&search=Трактор&limit=1&format=json&prop=info
```

Но в ответ я получаю это:

```
["\u0422\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440",["\u0422\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440"],[""],["https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80"]]
```

Вижу что он нашёл нужную страницу, но информационный текст с этой статьи он не выдает, лишь ссылка, `prop=info` указан подскажите пожалуйста что не так и почему он не возвращает текст статьи в ответе?(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользовавшись [песочницей](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) можно получить требуемые параметры для вывода статьи:

- `action=parse` Анализирует содержимое и возвращает вывод
- `format=json`
- `page=Трактор`
  Не может использоваться вместе с текстом и заголовком
- `prop=wikitext`
  Какую информацию получить:
- text
  Выдает проанализированный текст викитекста.
- langlinks
  Предоставляет языковые ссылки в проанализированном викитексте.
- categories
  Предоставляет категории в проанализированном викитексте.
- categorieshtml
  Предоставляет HTML-версию категорий.
- links
  Предоставляет внутренние ссылки в проанализированном викитексте.
- templates
  Предоставляет шаблоны в проанализированном викитексте.
- images
  Предоставляет изображения в проанализированном викитексте.
- externallinks
  Предоставляет внешние ссылки в проанализированном викитексте.
- sections
  Предоставляет разделы в проанализированном викитексте.
- revid
  Добавляет идентификатор редакции проанализированной страницы.
- displaytitle
  Добавляет заголовок проанализированного викитекста.
- subtitle
  Добавляет подзаголовок для проанализированной страницы.
- headhtml
  Выдает проанализированный тип документа, открытие , элемент и открытие страницы.
- modules
  Предоставляет модули ResourceLoader, используемые на странице. Для загрузки используйте mw.loader.using(). Либо, jsconfigvarsлибо encodedjsconfigvarsдолжны запрашиваться вместе с modules.
- jsconfigvars
  Предоставляет переменные конфигурации JavaScript, специфичные для страницы. Чтобы применить, используйте mw.config.set().
- encodedjsconfigvars
  Предоставляет переменные конфигурации JavaScript, специфичные для страницы, в виде строки JSON.
- indicators
  Предоставляет HTML-код индикаторов состояния страницы, используемых на странице.
- iwlinks
  Предоставляет межвики-ссылки в проанализированном викитексте.
- wikitext
  Предоставляет исходный проанализированный викитекст.
- properties
  Предоставляет различные свойства, определенные в проанализированном викитексте.
- limitreportdata
  Предоставляет отчет о лимитах в структурированном виде. Не выдает данных, если установлен disablelimitreport .
- limitreporthtml
  Предоставляет HTML-версию отчета о лимитах. Не выдает данных, если установлен disablelimitreport .
- parsetree
  Дерево синтаксического анализа XML содержимого редакции (требуется модель содержимого wikitext)
- parsewarnings
  Выдает предупреждения, возникшие при парсинге контента (в виде вики-текста).
- parsewarningshtml
  Выдает предупреждения, возникшие при разборе содержимого (в формате HTML).
- `formatversion=2`
  Форматирование вывода:
- 1
  Обратно-совместимый формат (логические значения в стиле XML, * ключи для узлов содержимого и т. д.).
- 2
  Современный формат.
  последний
  Используйте последний формат (в настоящее время 2), может быть изменен без предупреждения.